# cofirming a payout has reached external bank account

Tags: node.js, api, stripe-payments

when money is to be transferred from platform to connect account's external bank account, i am  doing a transfer from platform balance to connected account. on doing ***transfer*** a tr_xxxxx id is generated, as read in the docs transfer means only sending the amount from platform account to connect account, but the amount gets transferred to bank using ***payout*** after 2 days. then a payout id is generated.

so, i am unable to get how to track a transfer, that whether a particular transfer has reached an external bank or not.

I followed up with Stripe support team, they said to expand the payout object and then get the transfer id out of it.. but i tried expanding all the stripe objects but neither i am able to retrieve payout_id from transfer_id nor transfer_id from payout_id.

what flow should i follow such that i can see if a transfer was successful, if failed, i will have to reverse the transfer too, to the platform balance.

Answer (score 0):

You should [use webhooks to listen for failed payouts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#webhooks), and handle them when the `payout.failed` event is sent.

Comment: but when i create a transfer, i get transfer id and that is what stored in my app db. but payout webhooks has payout id.. how can i map a payout so as to match it with which transfer got succeeded and which one got failed.

Comment: The `destination_payment` property of the Transfer (https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/object#transfer_object-destination_payment) points to the payment in the Connected Account.  You'll want the Balance Transaction for that Payment, which contains an `available_on` attribute which says when it should be paid out (https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/object#balance_transaction_object-available_on).  From there, just get the Payout for that day and see if that Balance Transaction is included.

Comment: Alternatively, list all the Balance Transactions for the Payout from the `payout.failed` event (https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/list#balance_transaction_list-payout) and see if a payment is in there.